# Subclass needs to implement Interface property as static

Tags: c#

My intent is that any API wrapper projects we write in the future around 3rd party or even internal APIs that need a session will need to (should by expected team pattern) implement this interface because it will enforce commonality in terms of those API Wrapper projects because I know that any session classes will always have GetCurrentSession, RenewSession, etc. in them...so we have a consistent pattern in terms of common members to be implemented for concrete session classes.

So here's my interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an API end user based session
/// </summary>
public interface IAPISession
{
    #region Properties

    int SessionID { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the user ID.
    /// Note: type string since userID is not always int in 3rd party APIs 
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The user ID.</value>
    string UserID { get; }

    bool SessionHasExpired { get; }

    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }

    void LogOut(); // expires the session & sets SessionHasExpired

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Renews the session by returning a brand new session 
    /// if the existing session has expired.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IAPISession RenewSession();


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current API session
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IAPISession GetCurrentSession();

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Here is an implementation example:

```
public class FacebookSession : IAPISession
{
    private static FacebookSession _singletonInstance;

    private FacebookSession() { }

    #region Properties

    private HttpContext CurrentContext { get; set; }

    private HttpCookie CurrentSessionCookie { get; set; }

    #endregion


    #region IAPISession Members

    // Checks for a current session cookie
    public bool SessionHasExpired 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _singletonInstance == null;
        }
    }

    public IAPISession RenewSession()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current API session singleton instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if (SessionHasExpired)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // TODO: return the singleton instance here...

    }

    public void LogOut()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int SessionID { get; private set; }

    public string UserID { get; private set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; private set; }

    #endregion


    public void LogIn(HttpContext currentContext)
    {
        if (SessionHasExpired)
        {
            const string redirectUri = "http://localhost/Photo/FacebookOauth.aspx"; // page they will be redirected to after they auth
            string authUrl = ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("PayPalBaseUri") + "?client_id=" +
                             ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("PayPalClientID") +
                             "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;

            CurrentContext.Response.Redirect(authUrl); // redirect them to log in
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my problem.  A session is a singleton for the current user thread.  To access a singleton, that method `GetCurrentSession()` which I know all APIs we create will need to implement (will be totally different in HOW they will be implemented based on the API) I need the property to be a static property to get the singleton.

But you can't.  Because you can't have static members in an Interface.  So...yea I could take out the Interface pattern requirement but I really don't want to.

FYI this is not functional code above, I'm doing my initial coding of all this and trying to design it best.

**UPDATE:**

On the topic of factories, let me step back to give you more context in what I'm doing here.  I needed to get the right custom APIService object (I create a service class for every API wrapper to work with) based on what API wrapper I'm coding for, so I created a GetService factory (or at least attempted to..have not done a lot of factories) like below.  And in it you can see that all the methods are static, properties, etc.

Usage example for below would be:

```
FacebookService service = PhotoServiceFactory.CurrentPhotoUploadServiceFactory;
```

Thoughts?  I'm just trying to do the same for Session but feel I would like to actually expose the related session inside the Specific Service instance that I get back from the factory.  So for instance I'd be able to do something like this:

```
service.CurrentSession which would give me the current facebook singleton session.
```

The service here is FacebookService type because the factory went out to get it based on the API type I'm working with (API type is an Enum I created that has values like Facebook, Flickr, etc.)

```
    public class PhotoServiceFactory
    {
        private static PhotoServiceFactory _singletonInstance;

        private PhotoServiceFactory(){}

        #region Properties

        public static PhotoUploadServiceFactory CurrentPhotoUploadServiceFactory
        {
            get
            {
                _singletonInstance = _singletonInstance ?? (_singletonInstance = new PhotoUploadServiceFactory());
                return _singletonInstance;
            } 
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public static IAPIService GetAPIService(APIType apiType)
        {
            IAPIService apiService = null;

            switch (apiType)
            {
                // return the right service singleton instance
                // based on the API type that we're working with
                case APIType.Facebook:
                    apiService = FacebookAPIService.CurrentFacebookAPIService;
                    break;
                case APIType.Flickr:
                    apiService = null; // service not implemented
                    break;
                case APIType.PhotoBucket:
                    apiService = null; // service not implemented
                    break;
                case APIType.Picasa:
                    apiService = null; // service not implemented
                    break;
                case APIType.Kodak:
                    apiService = null; // service not implemented
                    break;
            }

            return apiService;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want to use these classes. Could you include an example of the code which would call these static methods? Possibly in the form of a unit test?

Comment: sure:  http://elbalazo.net/post/uml3.pdf.  That doesn't show how you'd call the GetCurrentSession but here's how I want to call it, pretty standard:  FacebookSession.GetCurrentSession();  so GetCurrentSession() is static and checking for an existing instance of FacebookSession.  But again then I end up having to take the requirement to have GetCurrentSession() out of the contract if it's always needing and oging to be access statically in all future projects (Related or not) that will implement my IAPISession and it doesn't make me feel good...I feel strongly that that method needs to be there

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the property to be static to get the singleton? An instance member can get at static members with no problem - it's the other way round that's tricky.

```
// This should compile with no problems
public IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    if (SessionHasExpired)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: return the singleton instance here...
}
```

If other code needs to get at the session statically, you could have another static member to do that.

Admittedly it's a bit of a design smell for an instance member to only refer to static variables (any instance of `FacebookSession` will *effectively* have the same session, if you're on the same thread) but it should work.

Comment: (this is my thinking currently as I work through this) In order to call GetCurrentSession I'd have to create a new instance of FacebookSession which goes against the fact that it's a singleton class and you can't create an instance of that in order to then call GetCurrentSession.  So lets say somewhere in code-behind, I need to get/check for the current session because I need to use is.  Well I should I think be able to just do FacebookSession.GetCurrentSession() and it will either return me the current static session or create a new one and return it...

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: You should think about using dependancy injection for giving your service its instance of the session - let the container worry about the lifecycle, not your service impl..

Comment: thanks Dan, have not yet gotten to IoC.  Still trying to get more comfortable with Interfaces.  Abstract classes are a piece of cake but incorporating interfaces and when to and opportunities to are not always clear in the beginning of a project...so I run into walls like this where my intent "might" be ok but then run into beginner walls like these.

Comment: (Admittedly it's a bit of a design smell for an instance member to only refer to static variables) Thanks.  So it's best practice not to have instance members reference static?

Comment: check out my updated thread above...added more context of what I'm attempting to provide and do overall outside of just the session.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: As I mentioned, you could have a static method *as well*... the instance method would just be to satisfy the interface. Of course, just not using a ThreadStatic would be another option... pass the session into everything that needs it.

Comment: But John, my thinking is that I'd then have to create an instance of lets say FacebookSession just to be be able to call the non-static GetCurrentSession and I don't want to have to create an instance...because this class is a singleton and you create the instance inside privately...singleton pattern.  If there is already an instance of FacebookSession, I can't create one anyway in order to make a call to GetCurrentSession right? The code that needs to get that session statically does not reside inside this class..would be one of my Service classes returned from that service factory

Comment: I am a little confused just because of inexperience so bare with me.

Comment: Having an instance method would be dumb.  I'd be having to create an instance of FacebookSession just to call GetCurrentSession() to get an instance floating around in memory of iteself!  And again since that's dumb and a static GetCurrentSession makes sense, it is a problem because now I can't enforce that be it being in the IAPISession Contract anymore!  So I guess I'm kinda screwed, end of story??  I will just have to come to grips that no, you can't put that int he contract even though you feel that static is essential to be in all of our session subclasses moving forward.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: You wouldn't have to create an instance of FacebookSession if you had a static method for static access *and* an instance method to implement the interface. You could implement the interface explicitly if you want. To be honest though, I suspect that moving away from your ThreadStatic model would be a better approach.

Comment: @John:  My main problem here is I cannot have a static method in an interface and it makes no sense to call an instance GetCurrentSession() method because then you'd be creating an object to get or try to get an instance of the same object you just created.  So is the conclusion here that I'm pretty much screwed due to the limitation and just take it out and move on even though it really makes sense to be part of the contract?  Every session needs a way to get at it..and I want enforce a common pattern which is that method.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: You're still missing my point. Have a static method in the concrete class for when you don't have an instance. Not in the interface, just in the concrete class. *Also* implement the interface with an instance method, probably by just calling the static method. It's ugly, but it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @John: Yea, ugly isn't what I would be willing to do.  So my conclusion is, what I'm trying to do is simply not possible...so get over it type of conclusion am I correct?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: The [ThreadStatic] nature is where the ugliness is coming from. It's fundamentally incompatible (in terms of elegance) with the idea that the interface provides a current session. To be honest, it's odd that a session would provide GetCurrentSession in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using **Extension methods** for interfaces to provide a common implementation for an interface method. You could declare this extension method in the same namespace/assembly as the interface so that when someone references the interface, the extension method will be there already for them to use.  In that implementation, you could use your singleton and it would be a static.

```
public interface IAPIWrapper
{
    string UserID { get; }
    bool SessionHasExpired { get; }
    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }
    void LogOut(); // expires the session & sets SessionHasExpired

    IAPISession RenewSession();
    IAPISession GetCurrentSession();
}

public static class IAPIWrapperImpl
{
    private static Session session = new Session(); // Instantiate singleton here

    // This is an extension method for the IAPISession RenewSession method
    // the this keyword before the first parameter makes this an extension method
    public static IAPISession RenewSession(this IAPIWrapper wrapper)
    {
         // implementation details
         // use session here
    }

    // This is an extension method for the IAPISession GetCurrentSession method
    // the this keyword before the first parameter makes this an extension method
    public static IAPISession GetCurrentSession(this IAPIWrapper wrapper)
    {
         // implementation details
         // use session here
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in this example, the extension method here is...?

Comment: I've added some comments. Please review http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx for more information on extension methods

Comment: thanks I know of and have actually created some extension methods in the past but just not with interfaces.

Comment: ah! did not see the "this"...got it.

Comment: but then like John was saying, you need to still fulfill the Interface contract by providing a non-static GetCurrentSession() method implementation...sooo?

Comment: Extension methods can be used as Static methods or instance methods on the object they are extending.  Extension methods "look" like non-static methods.

Comment: Extension methods would still not enforce that method to be in the contract..it wouldn't be in the contract which was my whole issue and frustration.  I'll just have to accept the fact that I can't put statics like this in there but then how do people create an Interface for common session concepts like this if that's the case?  I mean you'd want to ensure stuff like this is in there.

Comment: If by contract you mean the interface, then your interface will have the method defined.  Does a person have to use it? No. The consumers of your objects do not have to use anything you provide unless all of your methods require them to first do something (get a session token, set some state, etc etc)
The extension methods are only there to provide a common implementation for everyone who builds an object that implements an interface.  I'm not sure what you are intending when you are talking about "the contract".

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the interface to a class, make it abstract, and make all those methods abstract too.  Then you can put whatever static fields you want in that abstract base class.

Comment: yea but I'd prefer it to be an interface.  I don't need an abstract class as all these members are going to be implemented differently anyway.

Comment: Whether all the members are implemented differently is completely irrelevent to using an abstract class.

Comment: why would an abstract class make any difference here?  You still cannot add static members in an abstract class and subclasses can choose to even ignore the abstract stub if they desire unlike Interfaces (contracts) where you MUST implement that method somehow.

Comment: What do you mean "you still cannot add static members in an abstract class".  Of course you can.   But you are correct that you can't enforce any sort of contract with static methods.

Comment: "It is an error to use the static or virtual modifiers in an abstract method declaration". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Ha ha, obviously a static method itself can't be abstract.  But an abstract **class** may contain static members.  Re-read what you wrote above, "you still cannot add static members in an abstract class".  That statement is dead wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is static, there's really no way to force children to implement it. If you think about how Interfaces are typically used, it makes more sense. The typical use-case is something like:

```
var myInterfaceInstance = new SomeClassThatImplementsInterface();
myInterfaceInstance.InterfaceMethod();
```

My suggestion would be to create a Factory to get the different Singleton instances of IAPISession:

```
public class IAPISessionFactory
{
    public static IAPISession<T> GetInstance() where T : IAPISession
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(ConcreteSession)
            return ConcreteSession.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: but the thing is, I really want that method to be in the contract...but since that method is usually going to be returning a singleton, it needs to be static.  I just don't want to leave it out of the contract.

Comment: (My suggestion would be to create a Factory to get the different Singleton instances of IAPISession.) actually I have a factory already.  And I get the FacebookSession back from that factory...I still need to check if it's null or not (valid session or not)

Comment: @CoffeeAdict - That's still the responsibility of the concrete object. The point of throwing the Factory in front of it is that we don't care how the object is constructed (or whether it's a Singleton or not) as long as it is exposed via the Factory. Therefore, you don't need the GetCurrentSession in the Interface because we don't care how the instance of IAPISession gets created as long as we get a good one back.

Comment: check out my updated thread above...added more context of what I'm attempting to provide and do overall outside of just the session.

Comment: @Justin - I don't have a FacebookSession factory, I meant ServiceFactory & the service to expose the session via a property accessible through the service instance. But isn't having a consistent pattern in getting the session from the actual SessionObject itself (a method called GetCurrentSession) inside your Session class across the board beneficial?  On another note, you're saying the factory exposes it through its concrete method instead (factory being now an abstraction) and since the factory is not a singleton, you can get the session from the underlying session however you want

Comment: @Jusin, not trying to argue just learn here so take it as me challenging you so I can understand how to do this better or what not to do from more experienced architects.

Comment: @Justin going back to the fact that I do want GetCurrentSession in the contract, even using a factory in between still doesn't solve this because I need to satisfy the contract in that I need an instance method GetCurrentSession in my SessionObject

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - The point is that using a Factory hides the need for GetCurrentSession. Each object can implement its own way of getting an instance of itself. You rely on the Factory to call the correct one for you.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Let me ponder that...my mind is going against your intent because I just want all the sessions to be sure to have a GetCurrentSession regardless if a factory is delivering it or the session object itself.  Its' good to have a layer in between with a factory but I have to think about this more in terms of taking it out of the contract.  It just feels right that a getCurrentsession method is in the contract to me...when thinking about the overall session object and its duties

Comment: The point is though Justin that I want to enforce a certain pattern.  Using a factory is what I will do.  Leaving the implementation up to the subclass in how you get the session?  Yes.  But not fully.  I want new classes to at the least expose it via a GetCurrentSession method and that's what our pattern will be.  So implementation can be whatever, but I want to make sure we know that hey, all our session classes have this pattern specified by the Interface.  For example I could tell a new developer hey, it's easy to use because we have a method called x that gives you that across the board

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're looking for but you can use statics with an interface. Instead using

```
public static IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    if (SessionHasExpired)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: return the singleton instance here...

}
```

To meet the interface definition you would implement this privately and expose it to the interface

```
private static IAPISession GetTheCurrentSession()
{
    if (SessionHasExpired)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: return the singleton instance here...

}

public IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
{
return GetTheCurrentSession();
}
```

Comment: This smells to me--it implies you'll need to instantiate the class to access a static method.

Comment: Yea I should not have to instantiate it to access the static method, I agree..I don't like that.

Comment: To access the value through the interface you have to have an instance. Whoever downvoted me clearly doesn't understand C#.